# Scaling property of the Dirac- Delta function does not preserve normalization

Tags: normal-distribution, dirac-delta

The well known scaling property for the Dirac $\delta$-function (distribution) states (see [the Wikpedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Scaling_and_symmetry))

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\:\delta(a x) =\frac{1}{|a|}$$

Now we can generally consider $\delta(x)$ as the limiting case of a probability density function

$$p(x,\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\epsilon \sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2}$$

with

$$\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\:p(x,\epsilon) = 1$$

and

$$\delta(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\:p(x,\epsilon)$$

Assume now we spread the events over a different $x$-range by doing the linear scale transformation $x\rightarrow ax$, so $p(x,\epsilon)$ transforms to

$$p(ax,\epsilon)=\frac{1}{\epsilon \sqrt{\pi}} e^{-a^2x^2/\epsilon^2}$$

However, this function is not normalized anymore, as

$$\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\:p(a x,\epsilon) = \frac{1}{|a|}$$

Imagine $p(x)$ describes the way you spend a given amount of money over time, then here, by increasing the length of time ($|a|<1$), one would have miraculously gained money! Obviously, this is not possible. In order to qualify as a probability density function $p(a x)$ must be properly normalized (this is expressed in the ['Location-Scale Family' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family) of probability theory, see also [this link](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/dstephens/OldCourses/556-2007/Math556-11-Families.pdf)) i.e.

$$p(ax,\epsilon)=\frac{|a|}{\epsilon \sqrt{\pi}} e^{-a^2x^2/\epsilon^2}$$

With this normalized function, the increased period of time the money is spent is compensated by the smaller amounts you have to spend, so you correctly end up with the same total spent, i.e.

$$\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\:p(a x,\epsilon) = 1$$

However, if one generates the $\delta$-function from this, one finds

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\: \delta(a x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\: \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\: p(a x,\epsilon)  =1 $$

rather than $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\: \delta(a x)= \frac{1}{|a|}$ as stated throughout in the literature.

Can anybody see anything wrong with my argument?

EDIT: My argument above used the (by definition) normal property of the generating Gaussian distribution function if one generally interprets the Dirac $\delta$-function as the limit of a probability density function. In this sense it was an additional constraint that enables the use of a continuous mathematical function (in this case the Gaussian function) to approximate the actually discrete probability distribution.
However, this can actually also be derived without resorting to probability theory by considering $\delta$ as a distribution that acts as a 'unit impulse' function when applied to a test function $f(x)$ i.e.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\: \delta(x)f(x) = f(0) $$

Also with this interpretation, $\delta(x)$ can be interpreted as the limit of [$\delta$-sequences](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaSequence.html),  for instance

$$\delta_n(x)=\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-n^2x^2}$$

with the notation as defined in the link. If we set $n=\frac{a}{\epsilon}$ this becomes instead

$$\delta_{a,\epsilon}(x)=\frac{a}{\epsilon\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-a^2x^2/\epsilon^2}$$

which means

$$\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\:\delta_{a,\epsilon}(x) = 1 \neq \frac{1}{|a|}$$

Comment: densities are not functions, they are forms. $\rho(x)$ is meaningless, only $\rho(x)\mathrm dx$ has intrinsic meaning.

Comment: They are called probability density functions, in every book I have ever read about them.  They have inputs and outputs. I'm not a philosopher, and probability is particularly slippery in that regard.  But if you're going to go against standard terminology, you need to at least give some reason why you are doing so.

Comment: The point is that mathematical functions (like the Gaussian) are continuous, but probability has a discrete nature. Particle density functions in physics for instance only approximate the average discrete number of particles at a given point. In order for this to work, the continuous function (the probability density function) needs to be normalized.

Answer (score 2):

You define $\delta(ax)$ to be a sequence of normalized functions. But that is *not* the definition of $\delta(ax)$.

The definition of $\delta$ is that (with some abuse of notation)
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)\,f(x)\,dx = f(0)$$
for all functions $f$ continuous at $x=0.$ (The real definition actually limit $f$ to a smaller set of functions, but this works for now.)

The definition of scaling the argument, i.e. $\delta(ax)$ (with $a>0$) is that a variable change should work:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(ax)\,f(x)\,dx = \{ \text{ set } y = ax \}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(y)\,f(y/a)\,dy/a
= f(0/a)/a
= f(0)/a
\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a}\delta(x)\,f(x)\,dx.
$$
Since this should be true for all $f$ (continuous at $x=0$) we have
$$\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{a}\delta(x).$$
For $a<0$ we get
$$\delta(ax) = -\frac{1}{a}\delta(x)$$
so in general, for $a\neq0$ we have
$$\delta(ax) = \frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x).$$

---

Your formula $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,p(a x,\epsilon) = \frac{1}{|a|}$ is correct and  gives the correct formula for $\delta(ax)$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \, \delta(a x) \, f(x)
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \, p(a x, \epsilon) \, f(x)
= \{ y := ax \}
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dy}{|a|} \, p(y, \epsilon) \, f(y/a)
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dy}{|a|} \, \delta(y) \, f(y/a)
= \frac{1}{|a|} f(0/a)
= \frac{1}{|a|} f(0)
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dy}{|a|} \, \delta(y) \, f(y).
$$

Comment: You don't have to *define* that $\delta(ax)$ is a sequence of normalized functions. As shown above (bottom of my question), it falls naturally out of the definition of $\delta(x)$ as a series limit of normalized functions considering that the limit variable $\epsilon$ itself can be considered a scale factor (which preserves normalization). Without keeping the scaled distribution normalized, you change the scale but leave the probability density unchanged, so you end up with a total probability >1 if $|a|<1$

Comment: @Thomas. No, that last equality is not correct. Here is the correct one:
$$
\lim_{\beta\to 0}\:\frac{|a|}{\beta \sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\: e^{-(ax)^2/\beta^2} 
= |a| \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\: \delta(ax).
$$
You have
$$
\delta(x) = \lim_{\beta\to 0} \frac{1}{\beta\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2/\beta^2}
$$
so, replacing $x$ with $ax$ we get
$$
\delta(ax) = \lim_{\beta\to 0} \frac{1}{\beta\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-(ax)^2/\beta^2}.
$$
Please follow the rules of mathematics!

Comment: I can see where you are coming from with your argument, but I don't think it is mathematically consistent: if you accept that $\delta(x)$ can be defined as the limit of normal probability density functions, then this must also hold for $\delta(ax)$. This follows from the 'Location-Scale Family' theorem in probability theory. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family and also here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Families_of_densities

Comment: If $f$ is an ordinary function such that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx = 1$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(ax) \, dx = 1/|a|.$ If you care about consistency then you would accept this to be true also for a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) like $\delta.$ Are you confusing the generalized function concept 'distribution' with '[probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution)'?

Comment: Have you considered that simple high-school level calculus may not be appropriate here? If you define a distribution through probability density functions, then this adds additional constraints to be taken into account, namely that  the integrated probability has to be 1, even after s scale transformation (note that the second link you gave actually links itself to the very Wikipedia page I linked to above stating this). Anyway, on what grounds would you assume that the exponential factor $e^{-{a^2x^2}/\epsilon^2}$ is normalized with regard to $\epsilon$ (when doing the limit) but not $a$?

Comment: @Thomas. If you require distributions to be normalized then you are defining something else than [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). Then, for every distribution $u$ you would have $2u=u$ and normal mathematical laws would not apply. Obviously we have to differ between "ordinary distributions" and "Thomas distributions". For $\delta$ as an ordinary distribution, $\delta(ax)=\delta(x)/|a|.$ For $\delta$ as a Thomas distribution strange laws apply.

Comment: Whether one understands the $\delta$-function as a distribution or a probability distribution, it wasn't my idea to define it as a limit of a normalized function. And as defined, it stays normalized when changing the limit parameter $\epsilon$  i.e when scaling the function to a narrower width. And merely renaming the limit parameter from $\epsilon$ to $\epsilon/a$ can not make any difference here.

Comment: @Thomas. The $\delta$-distribution is not defined as a limit of normalized functions. It is defined as a linear functional that maps a "test function" $\varphi$ to $\varphi(0).$
The "Thomas distribution" $\delta$ stays normalized under scaling of its argument because you define it that way and introduce an extra factor to make it work. Please differ between "ordinary distributions" and "Thomas distributions"!

Comment: Thank you @md2perpe! I didn't devote enough time to nail down the discrepancy as thoroughly and exactly as you did.

Comment: /Quote/The δ-distribution ... is defined as a linear functional that maps a "test function" φ to φ(0) /Unquote/  $\delta(ax)$ doesn't map φ to φ(0) according to your math. In fact, if let's say φ(x)=1=const, it doesn't map to φ(x) anywhere unless a=1.

Comment: @Thomas. You are right, $\delta(ax)$ doesn't map $\varphi$ to $\varphi(0).$ That's because $\delta(ax) \neq \delta(x).$ Instead it maps $\varphi$ to $\varphi(0)/|a|.$ That's because $\delta(ax) = \delta(x)/|a|.$

Comment: @md2perpe /Quote/The δ-distribution is *not* defined as a limit of normalized functions/Unquote/  Wolfram Mathworld ( https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html ) seem to think otherwise: *The delta function is a generalized function that can be defined as the limit of a class of delta sequences* and they give half a dozen of functions that can be used for this, each of which stays normalized if the scale parameter $\epsilon$ changes

Comment: @Thomas. Physicists often define it as a limit, but mathematicians usually define it as the linear functional mapping $\varphi$ to $\varphi(0).$ A $\delta$ sequence is often create by taking one function $\psi$ such that $\int \psi(x)\,dx=1$ and setting $\psi_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon^{-1}\psi(\epsilon^{-1}x).$ It is true that $\psi_\epsilon$ is also normalized, but $\psi_\epsilon(ax)$ is *not* (unless $a=1$). Note that $\delta(ax)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \psi_\epsilon(ax)$ (in a distributional meaning), which implies identity (5), $\delta(ax) = |a|^{-1} \delta(x).$

Comment: @Thomas. [Here](http://www.math.chalmers.se/~hasse/distributioner_eng.pdf) you can learn some distribution theory. I had the author of that paper in the 'Functional Analysis' course, but not in the distribution theory course.

Comment: @md2perpe The functions used to generate the Dirac $\delta$ function are normalized for a reason, namely for the latter to act as a 'unit impulse' function such that you obtain the function value $f(0)$ when applied to a test function $f$. So if you have a generating function
$$\delta_{\epsilon,a}(x) = c*exp(-\frac{a^2x^2}{\epsilon^2}) $$
this requires a normalization factor $c=\frac{a}{\epsilon}$ so that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\: \delta_{\epsilon,a}(x) =1$$

Otherwise you could not even legitimatly use the $\delta$ symbol here as the function would not do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @md2perpe  Sorry, the normalization constant in my comment above should of course come out as  $c=\frac{a}{\epsilon \sqrt{\pi}}$

Comment: @Thomas. There is a normalization constant for $\delta$-sequences, but you add an extra normalization constant for $\delta(ax).$ That shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Thomas. What would it take for you to admit that you are wrong and all the literature about distribution theory is right, instead of believing that you are right and all the literature is wrong?

Comment: @Thomas As md2perpe says, the usual definition of the Dirac delta is not the one you claim.

Comment: @LL3.14 As I have explained above in detail, the usual scaling relationship for the Dirac delta is incorrect as it does not preserve the normalization of the delta function. Changing the scale of *any* distribution function without adjusting its density accordingly will lead to a violation of conservation laws in e.g. statistics, physics etc. For an application in the latter context see my paper at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325499504_Why_the_Lienard-Wiechert_Retarded_Potential_is_the_Result_of_a_Flawed_Derivation

Comment: It is not incorrect, it is not the one you would like it to be ... that's very different. What is the problem about saying that $\delta(ax)$ is not a probability distribution, but $|a|\,\delta(ax)$ is ? One can always invent a new notation, like $\nu_a = |a|\,\delta(ax)$. But one cannot change the Dirac delta notation that is almost 100 years old and used already a lot.

Comment: @LL3.14 Mathematics is not just about variable substitution but also about the constraints that have to be applied when any real meaning is appointed to a function. In this case it is e.g. the requirement that in statistics that the integral over all probabilities must be 1. You can not get a total probability larger than 1 through a scale transformation. . Not because I like it to be but because it is required by the actual meaning. So indeed, the scale transformed Dirac delta should be to $|a|\delta(ax) = \delta(x)$. However, the  standard rule says it is $\delta(x)/|a|$.

Comment: @Thomas. Are you perhaps confusing the word "[distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))" used for objects like $\delta$ with "[probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution)"?

Comment: +1, @md2perpe, $\delta(ax)$ is just not a **probability** distribution ... For example $e^{-x^2}$ is not a probability distribution (but still a function), but $\pi^{-1/2} e^{-x^2}$ is  a probability distribution. In the same way, $\delta(ax)$ is not a probability distribution (but still a distribution, in the sense of the theory of distributions, see the link of md2perpe) but $|a|\,\delta(ax)$ is both a distribution and a probability distribution. More clear ? :)

Comment: @LL3.14 What you are saying is correct, but you are still missing my point:   in all practical applications I can think of, $\delta(x)$ is considered a probability distribution. Now a scale transformed probability distribution must be again a probability distribution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family ) but in all those practical applications this is claimed to be given by $\delta(ax)$ rather than $|a|\delta(ax)$

Comment: About applications I know there is usually a density probability $g(x)$ and then the rescaling looks like $|a|\,g(ax)$ ? Do you have examples ?

Comment: @Thomas. In all applications where I have seen $f(\mu,\sigma; x):=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$ it is a probability distribution. Still, $f(\mu,\sigma; ax)$ is *not* a probability distribution when $|a|\neq 1.$

Comment: $f(\mu,\sigma, ax)$ is not a scale transformation, only $|a| f(\mu,\sigma, ax)$ is. You may indeed have seen applications where $f(\mu,\sigma, ax)$ is taken as the scale transformed probability distribution, but this is evidently wrong as it would allow total probabilities >1 . This is the whole point I was making.

Comment: @LL3.14 See for instance the accepted answer to this SE question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206249/deriving-the-lienard-wiechert-potentials which discusses the derivation of the electrostatic potential of a moving point charge for a finite interaction speed c (which results in a scale transformed charge distribution) This is common physics textbook stuff, but it effectively implies that $\delta(ax)$ is the scale transformed probability distribution, which violates the charge conservation (the total charge should be unchanged under a scale transformation of the distribution)

Comment: @Thomas. I still don't understand how you think. You say that $f(\mu, \sigma, ax)$ is not a scale transform, but you want $\delta(ax)$ to be it. Why should one be it but not the other? FYI, $\delta(x) = \lim_{\sigma\to 0} f(0, \sigma, x)$ in the meaning of limits of [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

Comment: No, what I am saying is  that $\delta(ax)$ is not a scale transform, but it is frequently incorrectly used as such. The scale transform should be $|a| \delta(ax)$ . See also my last comment to @LL3.14

Comment: @Thomas. What is your definition of a "scale transform"?

Comment: See this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_parameter  .  Applied to $\delta(x)$ this would require the scale transform to be $|a| \delta(ax)$. Taking $\delta(ax)$ as the scale transform would be equivalent to having the width of the curve changing in the animated graphics in this reference but the maximum height staying the same.

Comment: @Thomas. That article is about [probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution), not [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)). Note that $\delta(ax)$ is a distribution for all $a\neq 0,$ but only a probability distribution when $|a|=1.$ However, $|a| \, \delta(ax) = |a| \, \frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x) = \delta(x)$ is a probability distribution with scale parameter $a$ for all $a\neq 0.$

Answer (score 1):

Just about everything you wrote is correct.  However, you assumed that to produce $\delta(ax)$, you needed to use probability densities.  You don't.  $\delta(x)$ is the limit of probability densities, but $\delta(ax)$ is not.  So I think you are just having an interpretation issue.  $\delta(ax)$ is not normalized, and isn't supposed to be: as you said, its integral should be $\frac{1}{|a|}$.

Comment: On what grounds are you saying that $\delta(ax)$ can not be seen as the limit of probability densities? Just define $y=ax$, and by definition $\delta(y)$ can be described in the same way as the limit of e.g.a normal Gaussian function as $\delta(x)$. If you scale the overall size of the distribution without scaling the density in the inverse sense, you end up with a total probability larger or smaller than 1 though.

Comment: But you would have to integrate over $dy$, not $dx$.  I was using the condition that a probability density, specifically, must integrate to $1$, otherwise it's not a probability density but rather something proportional to one.

Comment: If you scale both the distribution and the units by the same amount, that wouldn't be a scale transformation anymore. It would be the same distribution.